# Reduce render file size in After Effects

Tags: after-effects, codec, compression

I am making a simple travel map, like the one in the Indiana Jones movies. I followed this tutorial:

(German)

When I want to save it as a video (render it), the video file is 5GB huge. However the length of the movie is only about 1min. I tried to reduce the resolution to a quarter, then the file is still 700MB large, but with very bad quality.

Should I use a different program to do this task?

Comment: What are your render settings? Sounds like you are using the lossless preset. Will you submit the file directly to Youtube..etc or import it in another program like a video editor? In any case, don't set the resolution to quarter, keep it full. We just need to specify the other settings.

Comment: I will be using it in a presentation.  I already tried this guide: http://www.surfacedstudio.com/blog/how-to-export-videos-from-after-effects. However it only reduces size by about 20%.

Comment: Instead of Quicktime, chose H264. And in the format options, choose profile High, and target bitrate of 10mbps VBR to start with. Tweak that (in either direction) till you are satisfied with quality and size.

Comment: Thanks Mulvya, that helped alot. I mean alot. From 5GB to 70MB.

Comment: Glad to hear it.

Comment: For best quality, render the file from After Effects using a lossless setting, then transcode it to h.264 using Media Encoder or something like Handbrake (free). It will do  a better job of compressing meaning higher quality and smaller files. It also means that you can try out different compression settings without having to re-render. You can chuck away the large file when you're done.

Answer (score 3):

You need to change the encoding settings. By default, AE uses the AVI animation codec, which is very good at retaining quality but creates incredibly large files. Using an intermediary codec like Apple Prores, Avid DNxHR, or GrassValley HQx would give you visually equivalent quality with a significantly smaller file size.

If that file size isn't small enough for you, then you may want to go to a compressed codec like h.264. Choosing h.264 with a bitrate of around 20-30Mbps would give you pretty good quality. The disadvantage of going to h.264 is that you'll lose a lot of visual information, making any additional editing such as color grading more difficult. You'll also be using a multi-frame encoding which makes scrubbing through an editing timeline very difficult.

Answer (score 1):

Here the simplest solution: After render video you just compress the video.  I recommended handbrake. 
https://handbrake.fr/downloads.php